# Somar variáveis para obter data de término

Tags: php, jquery, data

Tenho um formulário com um cadastro de locação. Nele, tenho os campos `$datainicio`, `$meses` e `$datatermino`. A data de início eu coloquei automático, de acordo com a data do dia. Os meses deverão ser colocados no momento do cadastro, sendo 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48 ou 60 meses.

O meu problema é o seguinte: Gostaria de pegar a variável `$datainicio` e somar com a variável $meses para obter o valor de `$datatermino`, tudo isso no momento do cadastro.

Sei que com PHP puro não consigo fazer isso. Tenho dificuldades com jQuery. Gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

`$datainicio + $meses = $datatermino.`

Comment: Sim é possível com PHP puro, acredite!

Comment: Sério? Se tiver alguma referência... imaginei não ser possível...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com o método [add()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) da classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) combinando com a classe [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). O que é feito é adição de um período determinado por uma string como `P10D`(10 dias);

```
$dataInicio = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '28/03/2016');
$dataInicio->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $dataInicio->format("d/m/Y"); //saida: 07/04/2016
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54275/discussion-on-answer-by-rray-somar-variaveis-para-obter-data-de-termino)

Answer (score 0):

É possível utilizar a função `strtotime()` do PHP para realizar diversas operações entre datas inclusive a de somar:

```
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Sao_Paulo');
$datainicio = '28-03-2016';
$meses = '2'; //adicionando meses
$datatermino= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$meses." months",   strtotime($datainicio)));

echo $datatermino;// Saída: 2016-05-28 , dois meses depois
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Obtem a data atual.
$date   =  date('Y-m-d'); //Data atual 29-03-2016    

//Quantidade em meses para somar a data
$qtdMes =  6

//"quebra" a data em 3 partes usando como delimitador o "-"
list($year, $month, $day)  =   explode( '-', $date );
```

//Usando a função mktime, podemos somar dias, meses, anos, horas, minutos e segundos

```
$date   =   mktime( 0 , 0 , 0 , $month + $qtdMeses, $day, $year );

//Mostra a data
echo date( 'd/m/Y', $date );
```

Uma outra forma de fazer isso é:

```
$date  =  date('d-m-Y', strtotime( '+ 2 mounths' ) );
```

Como parametro na função strtotime você pode usar `days`, `mounths` e `years`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizaria o `Datetime` combinado com o método `modify` para alterar de acordo com os meses que quero adicionar:

```
$mes_variavel = 3;

$datetime = new DateTime('2016-08-06');

$datetme->modify(sprintf('+%d months', $mes_variavel));

echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y');
```