# Somar int com date - PHP

Tags: php, data, int

Tenho a função abaixo, que faz a soma de data, com o valor *+2 days* fixo:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($ultima_data)));
```

Ele soma corretamente com o valor de *$ultima_data*, mas de alguma forma preciso alterar o *+2 days* para um valor que está em outra variável, mas até o momento não consegui. Tentei das formas abaixo, sem sucesso:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dias_frequencia,strtotime($ultima_data)));

echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+'$ultima_frequencia'days",strtotime($ultima_data)));
```

Em ambos casos não deu erro, mas retornaram valores de 1969...
Alguma idéia?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120381/91 e tira aquelas aspas simples ali.

Comment: Faltou um espaço aqui: `"+'$ultima_frequencia'days"` não seria assim `"+'$ultima_frequencia' days"`?

Comment: @rray valeu de novo. Mais uma que vou anotar no caderninho kkk. Guilherme Nascimento alterei tudo para aspas duplas, como na pergunta que o rray mandou e deu certo. Obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: Ah é verdade, eu nem me atentei a isto =)

Comment: Eu entendo que já faz muito tempo caro Diego, ainda sim acho que merecia uma resposta técnica: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/324727/3635 :)

Answer (score 2):

Sei que até o momento a pergunta provavelmente já foi resolvida, eu cheguei a comentar a falta de espaço:

> [Faltou um espaço aqui: `"+'$ultima_frequencia'days"` não seria assim `"+'$ultima_frequencia' days"`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120982/somar-int-com-date-php#comment252185_120982)

Mas havia me esquecido de mencionar também os apostrofos desnecessários, ou seja se fizer isto:

```
 echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+'10' days"));
```

Ele vai retornar 1969 ou 1970, algo como será exibido:

> 01/01/1970

Agora fazendo assim funciona:

```
 echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+10 days"));
```

No caso hoje sendo 24/08/2018 me foi exibido isto (este mês termina no dia 31):

> 03/09/2018

Ou seja o problema não é concatenar, na verdade com aspas duplas nem sempre é necessário concatenar e não causa problema de legibilidade usar variaveis dentro destas aspas, você pode até tornar mais visível usando algo como:

```
 echo "Olá $nome, você recebeu {$mail->mailbox[0]->messages}";
```

O que do meu ponto de vista é tão legivel quanto concatenar:

```
 echo "Olá " . $nome . ", você recebeu " . $mail->mailbox[0]->messages;
```

Answer (score 0):

faça desta forma:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+" . $ultima_frequencia  . " days",strtotime($ultima_data)));
```

Concatenando, seu código fica mais legível.